# Check My Proof: if $a$ is even then $9(a +5)$ is odd

Tags: proof-verification

Just want to make sure I am doing this right.

> If $a$ is an even integer then $9(a + 5)$ is odd

If $a$ is even, $a = 2k$, therefore, $9(a + 5) = 9(2k + 5)$ which is odd.

Comment: You should express $9(2k + 5)$ in the form $2m + 1$ for some integer $m$ to show that it is odd.

Comment: The idea is correct, I think you should explain clearly why at the end $9(2k+5)$ is odd.

Comment: Ok so to complete the proof would 9((2k +1) + 4) be correct?

Answer (score 2):

You need to justify the assertion that $9(2k + 5)$ is odd.

> If $a$ is even, then $9(a + 5)$ is odd.

If $a$ is even, then there exists an integer $k$ such that $a = 2k$.  Hence, 
\begin{align*}
9(a + 5) & = 9(2k + 5)\\
         & = 18k + 45\\
         & = 18k + 44 + 1\\
         & = 2(9k + 22) + 1
\end{align*}
Since the integers are closed under addition and multiplication, $9k + 22$ is an integer.  Therefore, $9(a + 5)$ has the form $2m + 1$ for some integer $m$, so it is odd.

Comment: oh ok I understand thanks